# Cron job not executing

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to use `cron` for the first time, and I'm stuck.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, and the following is my `/etc/crontab` file. The only modification that I've made is appending the last line.

I've verified that `cron` is running, and the other jobs here run, but the last one does not.

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
21 22   * * *   root    /etc/mycron/myscript.sh > /home/me/stuff/log/cron.log
```

I've checked `$ sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog` and found evidence of the hourly jobs, but nothing for the new job.

I've looked for `cron.allow` and `cron.deny` files, but they don't seem to exist on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to ask the obvious, but is `/etc/mycron/myscript.sh` executable?  You can check with:

```
ls -l /etc/mycron/myscript.sh
```

Should generally see 3 x's.  If not, try:

```
chmod -V +x /etc/mycron/myscript.sh
```

You can also use sh or bash to run the script, using this line in the cron instead:

```
sh /etc/mycron/myscript.sh
```

Comment: It is executable, thanks for asking. (Really) I'm curious what difference adding `sh` makes. (I'm trying it, I just don't have any idea what it could mean if it works.)

Comment: OK, adding `sh` made it work. What was `cron` trying to do when it wasn't there? I'd really appreciate some insight here, otherwise I'll superstitiously add `sh` to cron jobs indefinitely.

Comment: @EricWilson Cron executes the command through a shell. With a non-executable `myscript.sh` isn't executable, that shell emits the error message `/etc/mycron/myscript.sh: Permission denied` and moves on to the next instruction (i.e. exits, since this is the only instruction). The error message is sent through local e-mail to your account, like all output from a cron job. If you haven't installed an MTA, the cron job output is lost.

Comment: @Giles But my script *was* executable. I had executed it from the command line, and confirmed that all three `x`s were there.

Comment: How about the shebang?  Does the first line say:

    `#!/bin/sh`  or `#!/bin/bash` -- this may be your problem.